# Flutter Changenotifier class needs always to be passed in my functions

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a `FutureBuilder` receiving values from a function. This is my `FutureBuilder` with the new `context.watch` syntax

```
final dataNotifier = Provider.of<DataNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    returnFutureBuilder(
                future: DataService().getData(dataNotifier),
                // ignore: missing_return
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.none:
                      return Center(child: Text('No status', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),));
                      break;
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      break;
                    case ConnectionState.done:
                    
    
                    return Center(
                      child:  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(context.watch<Data>().myList[0].id, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                      Text(context.watch<Data>().myList[0].name, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                                    ],
                    ));
                   
                       //Center(child: Text('Data', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),));
                      break;
                    default:
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Everything just works fine as long I'm always passing the `dataNotifier` in every function. I'm not quite familiar with providers yet, how can I get that work without always passing the `dataNotifier`?

I assume I have to add something in my Changenotifier class? my future function `getData(dataNotifier)` ends with the following:

```
dataNotifier.myList = _myList;
```

And my `Changenotifier` class `DataNotifier`:

```
class DataNotifier with ChangeNotifier {


      List<Data> _myList = [];
      UnmodifiableListView<Data> get myList => UnmodifiableListView(_myList);
      set myList(List<Data> myList){
        _myList = myList;
        notifyListeners();
      }
```

Comment: You should embed your FutureBuilder in a ChangeNotifierProvider: like ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => DataNotifier(),
      child: FutureBuilder(),
    ),

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have the ChangeNotifierProvider for DataNotifier() on top of my app

Comment: I see, usually you would use the "dataNotifier" (ViewModel) class to call the service class (DataService) hidden in the dataNotifier not viceversa

Comment: Yes, when I don’t pass the notifier in the function and in the function it self I say DataNotifier().myList = _myList instead of „dataNotifier“ the notification doesn‘t work. I don’t know why, it seems like it is a different context/state. I edited my example, I forgot to change „Data“ to „DataNotifier“

Comment: Hello @Marcel first using Provider you do not need the FutureBuilder. Usually you use the DataNotifier to store the status of the application/view; when you draw the GUI (build) you do it reading the status from there. When you call notifyListeners then the ChangeNotifierProvider is called and the GUI is rebuilt with the new status.

Comment: hello @camillo777 thanks for the reply. Would you show me a small example? In that point its quite hard for me to follow you, since the structure you recommend is completely different from mine. That would be great to clear things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest working Provider example with a MVVM (Model, View, ViewModel) architecture is this below.

When data is loaded app is updated to display the new value.

You can replace the String data with anything you like, for example a list of items.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
    child: ChangeNotifierProvider<DataNotifier>(
        create: (_) => DataNotifier(), child: MyApp()),
  )));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dataNotifier = Provider.of<DataNotifier>(context);
    if (dataNotifier.dataLoaded) return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
      Text(dataNotifier.data),
      Text(
      dataNotifier.listData.fold("LIST: ", (previousValue, e) => "$previousValue [${e.id} ${e.name}]"),
    )]);
    return Text("Waiting...");
  }
}

class DataNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _dataLoaded;
  bool get dataLoaded => _dataLoaded;
  DataService _service;
  String _data;
  String get data => _data;
  List<SampleData> _listData;
  List<SampleData> get listData => _listData;

  DataNotifier() {
    _dataLoaded = false;
    _service = DataService();
    getData();
  }

  void getData() async {
    _data = await _service.getData();
    _listData = await _service.getListData();
    _dataLoaded = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class DataService {
  Future<String> getData() async {
    return Future<String>.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => 'Data Loaded',
    );
  }

  Future<List<SampleData>> getListData() async {
    return Future<List<SampleData>>.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => List.generate(100, (index) => SampleData(index, "name_$index")),
    );
  }
}

class SampleData {
  int id;
  String name;

  SampleData(this.id, this.name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me this! Now I can dive into the structure even better. I have some basic questions but dont want to annoy you with them. Could you simply extend your example by adding another function in DataService which gets different data then getData() for example in a list so we have multiple cases? I think then I can answer most of the questions I have by myself. Thanks again @camillo777

Comment: Hello @MarcelDz I have added more details, like a List of a custom class. Hope it helps!

Comment: It helps a lot. Today I learned a lot from you! Can you let me know how you are solving the following 2 cases? 1. Let's say we have to get some data which isn't on the first screen, i guess we wouldnt do it in getData() then right ? We would get that data at a later point then. Where and how would we implement that? 2.What if some of the data didn't load like it should, for example no internet or something else, how can we call this specific function again? @camillo777 interested in your guidance. If you like to you can extend your example, this is really great!

Comment: Hello @MarcelDz for (1): if you have another page (in this case another "MyApp", for example "MyApp2"), usually you have another ViewModel "MyApp2ViewModel" but the same DataService (if data is from the same service); or getData() can also be called by a button or any interaction of the user with the GUI.

Comment: (2) the DataService usually is in charge of getting the error if something goes wrong and maybe throwing an exception caught by the ViewModel (or returning a status code with the data) that can set a specific variable to show for example in the GUI that an error occurred and display a "Retry" button.

Comment: (2) alright nice! (1) Do I get it right, that means for MyApp Screen we have DataNotifier with ChangeNotifier and inside getData() with the Service we need and for MyApp2 we have let's say DataNotifier2 with ChangeNotifier and inside this getData() same Services but maybe other functions regarding to our needs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230893/discussion-between-marcel-dz-and-camillo777).

Comment: hey, hope youre doing well! I wrote you something in the chat, please check my message, would be great :)